# How do I share visual studio files?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I've written some code in Visual Studio that I would like to send to somebody else (who may or may not be using Visual Studio).

My question is, how do I do this?

I know where all the cpp and .h files are located. Are those the only ones I need to send? There are also these others files that end with .sln and .vcproj and so on. Are these irrelevant?

Or should I just send the entire folder, including all the solution and VS-related files?

Comment: You can share you project via GitHub or you need Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 where multiple developers can work in the same project.

Comment: This is not an answer to my question. I want to SEND it

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zebw5zk9.aspx

Comment: You can learn the file types https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3awe4781.aspx and then what should be excluded from source control https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore Usually we use Git to manage the files, and then you can share the Git repo with your friend, or simple a ZIP file from `git archive` https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive

Answer (score 2):

All the Cpp and header files make up your project, if someone wants to open your code having the code itself in the .h and .cpp files is enough, assuming you don't use any none-standard libraries, you can compress them in zip format and send them.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, I just right click the solution node, and select "Open Folder in File Explorer". Then I delete the ".vs", "Debug", "Release" directories. Note, for C++ projects there may be another set of "Debug" and "Release" directories in the project subdirectory.

This removes all the files you don't need to redistribute. Then I just zip the folder containing the solution file (.SLN) including all the subdirectories.

Note, many C++ projects are made up of more than just .h and .cpp files. The .vcxproj file contains all the details that make up your project, and how it's built. There may be resource files .RC files, .IDL files and others depending on what you're actually building. So you don't want to just limit yourself to passing along the .cpp and .h files.

If you just delete the stuff that gets built (the files that wind up in your Debug and Release subdirectories), and the .vs directory, and zip the remainder; that'll give you a .zip containing the minimal set of files required to rebuild your project.

Sincerely,